# How to set the same space between words after breaking a line?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

As illustrated in my picture, I can not have the same space after breaking a line. How to fix this problem? I know I can use \newline. But how to do this automatically?

[image]

Comment: `\raggedright` .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but \raggedright make the right ragged

Comment: Yes so does placing `\newline` by hand. The width of the letters is fixed (or almost fixed, if you allow microtype) so either you justify the margins by allowing space to stretch, or you do not allow space to stretch and do not justify  margins. You can have one or the other, it's your choice, but you can't have both.

Comment: That said your image shows the spacing around = stretching far more than the space between words which looks very odd and suggests the markup is wrong but as you have provided no test document that produces that image, we can't comment on your markup.